# How to obtain timezone of a particular area in android

Tags: android, timezone

I need to find the time zone of a area as my application will be available almost everywhere..
So i need to find the time zone so that i can send notifications as per the time of a day... how to find out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the Timezone of the Device that is running your application with
   TimeZone.getDefault();
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault%28%29